# Google Celebrity Search Result API?

Tags: api

I found that in Google, when you type a celebrity's name in the search bar, there is a side bar with a portrait photo of that celebrity, a brief description and some other related information and related people. 
I am wondering if this is already wrapped in some API provided by Google, since my app really need to collect this sort of information (we currently use wiki API). Could anyone give me a link or suggestion about it? And/Or maybe some other API gives similar information?(I would like to compare those result)
Thanks in advance.